# toggle button and text : working fine, but want to simplified the code as its too long and lengthy

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, pseudo-class

I have some boxes that a lot of information inside them. I want the information less at first and if the user wants to read more information, they click the button "See More". Then if they click that button, the button named "Copy" will be displayed, and the button named "See More" will be changed into "See Less" through innerHTML.

The code below is working properly but there's a lot of Code. Is there a possibility to make the code shorter?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Page title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

<div class="box">

    <div class="content">

<p>This Is a Content Example</p>

    </div>

    <div class="BTN">

<button class="SM">See More</button>

<button class="Copy">Copy</button>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="box">

    <div class="content">

<p>This Is a Content Example</p>

    </div>

    <div class="BTN">

<button class="SM">See More</button>

<button class="Copy">Copy</button>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="box">

    <div class="content">

<p>This Is a Content Example</p>

    </div>

    <div class="BTN">

<button class="SM">See More</button>

<button class="Copy">Copy</button>

    </div>

</div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>

<style>

*{

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

outline: none;

}

body{

    width: 100%;

    height: 100vh;

    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;

}

.wrapper{

    width: 90%;

    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

}

.box{    

    height: 180px;

    background: blue;

    width: 100%;

    margin-top: 10px;

}

.content{

    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;

}

.content p{

    font-size: 22px;

    color: white;

    font-weight: bold;

}

.BTN{

    position: relative;

    width: 90%;

    margin: auto;

    display: flex;

    justify-content: space-between;

    gap: 8px;

    height: 32px;

    margin-top: -37px;

}

.BTN button{

    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

    font-size: 18px;

    background: yellow;

    color: red;

    font-weight: bold;

    border: none;

    border-radius: 5px;

}

.Copy{

    display: none;

}

@media(min-width: 600px){

.wrapper{

    flex-direction: row;

    gap: 10px;

}

}

</style>

<script>

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("SM");

var b = document.getElementsByClassName("Copy");

a[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(a[0].innerHTML == "See Less"){

    a[0].innerHTML = "See More";

    b[0].style.display = "None";    

    }else{

    a[0].innerHTML = "See Less";

    b[0].style.display = "block";

    }

});

a[1].addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(a[1].innerHTML == "See Less"){

    a[1].innerHTML = "See More";

    b[1].style.display = "None";    

    }else{

    a[1].innerHTML = "See Less";

    b[1].style.display = "block";

    }

});

a[2].addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(a[2].innerHTML == "See Less"){

    a[2].innerHTML = "See More";

    b[2].style.display = "None";    

    }else{

    a[2].innerHTML = "See Less";

    b[2].style.display = "block";

    }

});

b[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

    alert("You Copied the First Info");

    /* Please Create a Code To Copy because I already know and this is a sample. But if there's a possibility to make this code shorter, please include this.*/

});

b[1].addEventListener("click", function(){

    alert("You Copied the Second Info");

});

b[2].addEventListener("click", function(){

    alert("You Copied the Third Info");

});

</script>
```

Anyway, if there's a possibility to make the code shorter in JQuery, then I want to accept it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: The easiest way to make the code shorter is to not double space it

Comment: You can achieve a script-less open/close logic by using `<details>` and `<summary>` elements, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same via jquery with very simple code.

Working Example:

```js
$('.SM').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.Copy').toggle(); // hide show copy button
  //code to change button text
  $(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "See More" ? "See less" : "See More";
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  height: 180px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.BTN {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: -37px;
}

.BTN button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Copy {
  display: none;
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <p>This Is a Content Example</p>
      </div>
      <div class="BTN">
        <button class="SM">See More</button>
        <button class="Copy">Copy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <p>This Is a Content Example</p>
      </div>
      <div class="BTN">
        <button class="SM">See More</button>
        <button class="Copy">Copy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <p>This Is a Content Example</p>
      </div>
      <div class="BTN">
        <button class="SM">See More</button>
        <button class="Copy">Copy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: Make sure the jQuery library is included on your page otherwise this code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Array forEach can help

`[...a]` creates an Array from `a`

`.forEach((el, i)` gives you an index (`i`) for the appropriate `b` and you can use `el` instead of `a[i]` - up to you really

```
const a = document.getElementsByClassName("SM");
const b = document.getElementsByClassName("Copy");
[...a].forEach((el, i) => a.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (el.innerHTML == "See Less") {
        el.innerHTML = "See More";
        b[i].style.display = "None";
    } else {
        el.innerHTML = "See Less";
        b[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}));
[...b].forEach((el, i) => b.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert(`You copied ${['First', 'Second', 'Third'][i]} Info`);
}));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but in "Alert" Section that if you copy every information, that's not my point. The exact point for that is to insert every function in respective Information. Like for example, if you click the Copy in first box, the function you insert is "CopyInfoA(); then in the second box the function will be "CopyInfoB(); and so on..

Comment: Sorry, @BeAlwaysMine, my mind reading failed - rewrote what I saw, not the playng card you thought about ... was it the 3 of hearts?

Comment: Like for example, this code must be like this [...b].forEach((el, i) => b.addEventListener("click", function () {
    ${['CopyInfoA()', 'CopyInfoB()', 'CopyInfoC()']}
});

Comment: but ... you didn't have that code in your question ... was it the 5 of spades?

Comment: The console log says Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: does it? you're right, I missed a `)` in the function you are saying is wrong because it does exactly what your code in the question does rather than something you expected me to guess it does

Comment: I also missed `[i]` in that function too - was an afterthought since in your question you didn't want any rewrite of that function anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your original post you require 2 parts to your solution: the first is making your overall code shorter/simplified and the second is to leverage the use of JQuery to do so.

We can skip using the direct functionality to edit and read the DOM (i.e. innerHTML and getElementsByClassName) since we can use jQuery to handle the click events and dynamically update the content of each box.

First we will condense the markup & styling. Notice that we only have the div with the "wrapper" class. We will use this as our starting point to generate the box contents.

Next we will update our script to generate the content using jQuery as well as enable all of the necessary functionality. Note, make sure to include the latest version of the jQuery library.

Since the original post contained three boxes we have created a const called boxContents which contains a value for each box. This value will appear when you click on the 'See More' button. When the document loads for the first time, jQuery will trigger the function generateBoxes which will run through the array provided by boxContents. This will generate the necessary HTML for us instead of needing to manually add it for each individual box.

Now that we have our boxes we need to create the two events for the buttons. This can also be done in jQuery. Note that in the script we need to use .wrapper as our starting point in the reference. This is because we are generating the html for the boxes after the DOM loads. If we try to make .SM and .Copy a direct reference like this:

```
$('.SM').on('click', function () {});
```

Then the code will not run. In both of our event functions we track the index of the button. This index is based on the correlating value of the boxContents. For the 'See More' button it triggers the toggleContent function which will add the value in boxContents to the correlating box.

Edit: To enable separate functions for each box we can use the value of `const index` as a reference. If the value is 0 for example, then we can run the first function. We can also use the value to get the appropriate content. In the code snippet below we take the value of `boxContents` and pass it through to the appropriate copy method.

The full example is shown below:

```js
// Array containing the content for each box
const boxContents = [
   'This is the first box content',
   'This is the second box content',
   'This is the third box content'
];

// Function to toggle content visibility and button text
function toggleContent(index) {
   const boxContent = $('.content p').eq(index);
   const seeMoreBtn = $('.SM').eq(index);
   const copyBtn = $('.Copy').eq(index);

   if (seeMoreBtn.text() === 'See More') {
       boxContent.text(boxContents[index]);
       seeMoreBtn.text('See Less');
       copyBtn.show();
   } else {
       boxContent.text('This Is a Content Example');
       seeMoreBtn.text('See More');
       copyBtn.hide();
   }
}

// Click event for "See More" buttons
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.SM', function () {
   const index = $('.SM').index(this);
   toggleContent(index);
});

// Click event for "Copy" buttons
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.Copy', function () {
   const index = $('.Copy').index(this);
   const copyValueFromBox = boxContents[index];
   if(index == 0) {
       copyA(copyValueFromBox);
   } else if(index == 1) {
       copyB(copyValueFromBox);
   } else if(index == 2) {
       copyC(copyValueFromBox);
   }
});

// Function to generate the dynamic markup for boxes
function generateBoxes() {
   const wrapper = $('.wrapper');

   // Iterate through boxContents array and create the markup for each box
   for (let i = 0; i < boxContents.length; i++) {
       const boxMarkup = `
           <div class="box">
               <div class="content">
                   <p>This Is a Content Example<\/p>
               <\/div>
               <div class="BTN">
                   <button class="SM">See More<\/button>
                   <button class="Copy">Copy<\/button>
               <\/div>
           <\/div>
       `;
       wrapper.append(boxMarkup);
   }
}

function copyA(boxValue) {
   alert('You clicked copyA, the value you are copying is: ' + boxValue);
}

function copyB(boxValue) {
   alert('You clicked copyB, the value you are copying is: ' + boxValue);
}

function copyC(boxValue) {
   alert('You clicked copyC, the value you are copying is: ' + boxValue);
}

// When the document is ready, generate the boxes and enable the functionality
$(document).ready(function () {
   generateBoxes();
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box{
    height: 180px;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.content p{
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.BTN{
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 8px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: -37px;
}
.BTN button{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.Copy{
    display: none;
}
@media(min-width: 600px){
    .wrapper{
        flex-direction: row;
        gap: 10px;
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort even it priceless.

Comment: Hello Dylan Hernandez, can I ask a favor again? In click event copy buttons, what if I going to create a function like CopyA() in first boxes, then CopyB() in second boxes instead of alert? Because the alert on that code is example, that if you click copy, it show any function respectively in every boxes. So if the user select the copy in 3rd boxes, the function CopyC() will activate. Anyway if you didn't understand, I'll give you a code .

Comment: @BeAlwaysMine in the copy function you can use the index as a reference to determine which copy function to run. For example if index is 0 (the first box) then you can run CopyA(), if it is 1 (the second box) then you can run CopyB() and so on. You can also use the index to pull the value of the box directly within the event function. In the above example if you write boxContents(index) and index is 0, the value will be 'This is the first box content'. Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: I dont know how to put the code on there. But can you check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76835160/i-want-the-user-that-if-they-click-the-copy-theres-a-function-will-be-activate  I post it to watch the code

Comment: @BeAlwaysMine I have updated the above post with the code for enabling independent copy functions. For example the first box will run CopyA(), the second box will run CopyB() and the third will run CopyC(). If any clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: OP asked for shorter code... Also this is not very scalable if you need a separate function for every single box.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode you are correct about the lack of scalability by using individual copy functions. My intention was to integrate the suggestion by OP based on the link provided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76835160/i-want-the-user-that-if-they-click-the-copy-theres-a-function-will-be-activate. Ideally, the copy functions should be coalesced into a single copy function and then OP can use the value of `index` to handle the unique functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with just toggling the visibility of the copy button. Rather than trying to mutate the text of the other button, you could just have all of the buttons exist, set the initial state in the css, and then let [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method handle all the details about state.

Then, instead off adding an event listener for every single element, you can use the jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. If you attach it to a parent element, you can use the second argument as a selector when a child element event bubbles to the parent.

Also I'd recommend setting yourself up for success by naming things what they are, rather than cryptic names like `BTN` or `SM` which are not fun to deal with on larger projects.

```js
$('.buttons')
  .on('click', 'button.see-more, button.see-less', function() {
    $(this).parents('.buttons').find('button').toggle();
  })
  .on('click', 'button.copy', function() {
    let $box = $(this).parents('.box');
    alert(`copied the ${['first','second','third'][$box.index()]} box:\n"${$box.find('.content').text().trim()}"`);
  });
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;}

body{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;}

.box{
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;}

.content{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;}

.content p{
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;}

.buttons{
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: -37px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;}

.buttons button{
  background: yellow;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;}

.buttons button.copy,
.buttons button.see-less{
    display: none;}

@media(min-width: 600px){
  .wrapper{
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <p>This Is a Content Example One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="see-more">See More</button>
      <button class="see-less">See Less</button>
      <button class="copy">Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <p>This Is a Content Example Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="see-more">See More</button>
      <button class="see-less">See Less</button>
      <button class="copy">Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <p>This Is a Content Example Three</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="see-more">See More</button>
      <button class="see-less">See Less</button>
      <button class="copy">Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```