# I want the user that if they click the Copy, there's a function will be activated respectively. Can you do this on JQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, indexing

If the user click the "Copy" button in first box, the function CopyA() will be activated. Then CopyB() on Second Box and so on. Make sure that click the "See More" first to make the "Copy" button displayed.

The code below have 4 functios on the lower part, the CopyA(); CopyB(), CopyC() and CopyD(). I want to functionize them one by one if the user click on Copy respectively.

```js
// Array containing the content for each box

const fullContents = [
  'This is the Full First box content',
  'This is the Full Second box content',
  'This is the Full third box content',
  'This is the Full fourth box content'
];
const boxContents = [
  'This is the first box content',
  'This is the second box content',
  'This is the third box content',
  'This is the fourth box content'
];

// Function to toggle content visibility and button text
function toggleContent(index) {
  const boxContent = $('.content p').eq(index);
  const seeMoreBtn = $('.SM').eq(index);
  const copyBtn = $('.Copy').eq(index);
  if (seeMoreBtn.text() === 'See More') {
    boxContent.text(fullContents[index]);
    seeMoreBtn.text('See Less');
    copyBtn.show();
  } else {
    boxContent.text(boxContents[index]);
    seeMoreBtn.text('See More');
    copyBtn.hide();
  }
}
// Click event for "See More" buttons
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.SM', function() {
  const index = $('.SM').index(this);
  toggleContent(index);
});
// Function to generate the dynamic markup for boxes
function generateBoxes() {
  const wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  // Iterate through boxContents array and create the markup for each box
  for (let i = 0; i < boxContents.length; i++) {
    const boxMarkup = `
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>null</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="BTN">
                        <button class="SM">See More</button>
                        <button class="Copy">Copy</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
            
    // EDIT: added this
    wrapper.append(boxMarkup)
  }
}

// When the document is ready, generate the boxes and enable the functionality
$(document).ready(function() {
  generateBoxes();
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('SM');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].click();
    setTimeout(function() {
      elements[i].click();
    }, 1);
  }
});
//THIS IS MY PROBLEM   
//IF YOU CLICK THE COPY ON FIRST BOX, THE CopyA() will be activated
//Can you create a code on JQuery on "Click Copy Event?"
function CopyA() {
  alert("You Copy 1");
  //The alert is an example only. I want to change that code if I trasnfer on my web.
}

function CopyB() {
  alert("You Copy 2");
}

function CopyC() {
  alert("You Copy 3");
}

function CopyD() {
  alert("You Copy 4");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  height: 180px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.BTN {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: -37px;
}

.BTN button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Copy {
  display: none;
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-cale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hint: search for `onclick` event in javascript

Comment: No, please understand my code, you cannot put onclick event inside the dynamic markup.

Comment: If you put onclick event inside it, all copy button has same onclick or functions

Answer (score 0):

As for adding the event listeners, here's a way to do that.
In order to match the function to the button, I've used a dictionary array and built the string of the function, to evaluate it. Using `eval` is discouraged but it works. It would have been better to assign the functions to an array, and call them by the index.

```js
// Array containing the content for each box

const fullContents = [
  'This is the Full First box content',
  'This is the Full Second box content',
  'This is the Full third box content',
  'This is the Full fourth box content'
];
const boxContents = [
  'This is the first box content',
  'This is the second box content',
  'This is the third box content',
  'This is the fourth box content'
];

// Function to toggle content visibility and button text
function toggleContent(index) {
  const boxContent = $('.content p').eq(index);
  const seeMoreBtn = $('.SM').eq(index);
  const copyBtn = $('.Copy').eq(index);
  if (seeMoreBtn.text() === 'See More') {
    boxContent.text(fullContents[index]);
    seeMoreBtn.text('See Less');
    copyBtn.show();
  } else {
    boxContent.text(boxContents[index]);
    seeMoreBtn.text('See More');
    copyBtn.hide();
  }
}

// Function to generate the dynamic markup for boxes
function generateBoxes() {
  const wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  // Iterate through boxContents array and create the markup for each box
  for (let i = 0; i < boxContents.length; i++) {
    const boxMarkup = `
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
              <p>null</p>
            </div>
            <div class="BTN">
                <button class="SM">See More</button>
                <button class="Copy">Copy</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;

    // EDIT: added this
    var dict = 'ABCD'.split('');
    var elem = $(boxMarkup);
    elem.find('.content p').text(boxContents[i]);
    elem.find(".Copy").click(function() {
      var foo = "Copy" + dict[i];
      eval(foo + '()');
    });
    wrapper.append(elem)
  }
}

// When the document is ready, generate the boxes and enable the functionality
$(document).ready(function() {
  generateBoxes();

  // Click event for "See More" buttons
  $('.wrapper').on('click', '.SM', function(elem) {
    const index = $('.SM').index(this);
    toggleContent(index);
    //toggleContent(elem);
  });


});

function CopyA() {
  alert("You Copy 1");
  //The alert is an example only. I want to change that code if I trasnfer on my web.
}

function CopyB() {
  alert("You Copy 2");
}

function CopyC() {
  alert("You Copy 3");
}

function CopyD() {
  alert("You Copy 4");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  height: 180px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.BTN {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: -37px;
}

.BTN button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Copy {
  display: none;
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-cale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I mean. If I extend the functions then I will put or extend the dict also as ABCDEFGHI... and so on.

Comment: but what will be after `Z` ?

Comment: Ouch, can I ask a favor again? what if After Z then I add the function CopyAB()? Because the AB will be split into two char which is A and B and also the function CopyA and CopyB() will be activated. How to make a function in 27th box (after CopyZ() because the English Alphabet is composed of 26 letters) if I used function CopyAB()? Thank you in advance.

Comment: using numbers will be easier. as for the `'ABCD'.split` it's just a shortcut for `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

Comment: How you put that on JQuery? I'm sorry but as of now, Im not expert when it comes to JQuery?

Comment: I put the ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].split but its not working. It said on console that ..Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') ... the error was find on section where ...var foo = "Copy" + dict[i];... is located

Comment: Okay, the problem is SOLVED, I made a typo.  I removed the word "split" based on your example in your replied comment